# Does $x^y, y^x \in \mathbb{Q}, x\neq y$ imply $x, y \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: real-numbers, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Title says it all. It's simple to find irrational numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x^y$ is rational. If we want to have both $x^y$ and $y^x$ be rational, we can make the constraint 'easier' by just requiring $x=y$ so that the two conditions are equivalent, and then solving (for instance) the equation $x^x = 2$. But what if we have two distinct numbers?

My intuition says no, of course -- that there are irrational $x \neq y$ with $x^y, y^x \in \mathbb{Q}$. But I'm not sure how to show this. My first thought is taking something like $y=2x$, so that
$$x^y = x^{2x} = (x^x)^2 = ((y/2)^x)^2 = (y^x)^2 \cdot 2^{-2x}$$
...but then that's not useful unless $2^{-2x}$ is rational, which is difficult to satisfy while also satisfying $x^y \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint : there are positive $x,y$ such that $x^y=2$ and $y^x=3$.

Comment: I suppose you also have to indicate why $x$ and $y$ are irrational.

Comment: Thanks! This definitely does make it intuitively obvious that it's true, and is also easy to verify. I shouldn't post questions when I'm sleepy, haha! :)

Comment: @GerryMyerson I can show they are not both rational using arithmetic and prime factorization, but I'm not sure that they are both irrational.

Comment: $2.2392502601704614^{1.3628039588284022}=3;\quad1.3628039588284022^{2.2392502601704614}=2\quad$ Seems to me pretty improbable  they are rational. After all the ratio diagonal/side in a square is irrational and those numbers above are much "messy". Have you noticed that many elementary functions are irrational (if not trascendental) at integer values. $\log n;\;\sin n;\;e^n\ldots$

Comment: @Raf, $\log n$ is not irrational at the integer value $n=1$; ditto $\sin n$ and $e^n$ at $n=0$. "pretty improbable they are rational" – well, sure, the rationals form a set of measure zero. But that doesn't prove anything.